# How to add lines together from two different paragraphs?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, input

I'm trying to figure out how to input two different paragraphs with short lines (similar to how song lyrics are structured) and then combine them. One of them would have its first line first followed by the other paragraph's line under it, and so on.

Something like this:

Input 1:

```
this is an example
line that is a run
on sentence
```

Input 2:

```
i am another example
paragraph that is
very similar
```

Output:

```
this is an example
i am another example
line that is a run
paragraph that is
on sentence
very similar
```

I'm guessing it can be done with a for loop but I'm unsure how you would grab the lines and put them one after the other. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you done any attempt ? Do you expect others to write the code for you ?

Comment: No, I'm not really sure how I would approach this at all.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm using Python 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the string module functions.  string.splitlines creates a list separated by newlines.  The string.join function joins elements in a list by whatever characters come before the dot.  For example:

```
import string

lyric1 = """this is an example 
line that is a run
on sentence"""

lyric2 = """i am another example
paragraph that is
very similar"""

def merge_lyrics(l1,l2):
    l1 = l1.splitlines()
    l2 = l2.splitlines()
    lyrics = []
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        lyrics.append(l1[i])
        lyrics.append(l2[i])
    return("\n".join(lyrics))


mylyrics = merge_lyrics(lyric1,lyric2)
print mylyrics
```

Answer (score 2):

How's this?

```
input1 = """
this is an example
line that is a run
on sentence
"""

input2 = """
i am another example
paragraph that is
very similar
"""

input1_lines = input1.strip().splitlines()
input2_lines = input2.strip().splitlines()

for line1, line2 in zip(input1_lines, input2_lines):
    print("{}\n{}".format(line1, line2))
```

**Output**

```
this is an example
i am another example
line that is a run
paragraph that is
on sentence
very similar
```

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late already, but here's another method:

```
a = """ this is an example 
 line that is a run
 on sentence"""

b =  '''i am another example
 paragraph that is
 very similar'''

a_list = a.split("\n")
b_list = b.split("\n")

c = [[x, b_list[index]] for index, x in enumerate(a_list)]
c_string = "\n".join(x for i in c for x in i)
```

output is a string, like this:

`' this is an example \ni am another example\n line that is a run\n paragraph that is\n on sentence\n very similar'`

EDIT:
or you can do it in one line

```
c = "\n".join(x for i in [[x, b.split("\n")[index]] for index, x in enumerate(a.split("\n"))] for x in i)
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing about izip is, what is the output of:

```
input1 = """
this is an example
line that is a run
"""

input2 = """
i am another example
paragraph that is
on sentence
"""

input1_lines = input1.strip().splitlines()
input2_lines = input2.strip().splitlines()

for line1, line2 in zip(input1_lines, input2_lines):
    print("{}\n{}".format(line1, line2))
```

So as an addition:

```
input1 = [
    'this is an example',
    'line that is a run',
]

input2 = [
    'i am another example',
    'paragraph that is',
    'on sentence',
]

output = ''
for i in range(3):
    output += input1[i] + '\n' if len(input1) > i else '\n'
    output += input2[i] + '\n' if len(input2) > i else '\n'
print(output)
```

You can check it at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to enter data into program. You may use `input()` function to enter single line, if you need more you may create you own `inp()` function based on standard `input`. Like so:

```
    def inp():
        res = []
        line = input()
        while line != '':
            res.append(line)
            line = input()
        return res
```

Try to run it in console and enter several lines. Empty line is end of input:

```
>>> d1=inp()
this is an example
line that is a run
on sentence
>>>
>>> print(d1)
['this is an example', 'line that is a run', 'on sentence']
```

The same for d2:

```
>>> d2=inp()
i am another example
paragraph that is
very similar
>>> print(d2)
['i am another example', 'paragraph that is', 'very similar']
```

Next you have to mix them. It's easy to do using `zip` method to group elements into pairs and then `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to flatten a list of pairs. Like:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(d1,d2)))
['this is an example', 'i am another example', 'line that is a run', 'paragraph that is', 'on sentence', 'very similar']
```

You may `join()` this array into one line with `'\n'` as a delimiter and `print` it:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(d1,d2))))
this is an example
i am another example
line that is a run
paragraph that is
on sentence
very similar
```